# C/C++ library as FTP server

Tags: c++, linux, ftp

I have to add a ftp server to my C++ program so it can receive some files.
Do you know any library out there in C or C++ ?

Comment: Do you want an FTP server, which runs and waits for clients to connect to it, or an FTP client, which connects to a server and then usually downloads files?

Comment: What I want is a server that bind on a port and  wait for clients to connect. So, once connected, the clients can send files to my program that will store them on the local directory. Also, clients can connect and download some files from the program

Comment: I have found what I'm looking for. http://sourceforge.net/projects/cftpserver/

Answer (score 4):

This one is exactly what I'm looking for: http://sourceforge.net/projects/cftpserver

It's a nice class of two files only where you can start, stop the server, set port, 
add users that can connect and their home directory etc ...

Comment: I used this class already for some years - but it contains some pitfalls, especially when integrating into a Qt environment. Thus I'm currently writing an own FTP server as C++ classes integrated to Qt.

Comment: @3DH Did you manage to make your c++ ftp server library? I'm currently working with a project that requires an FTP server. Let me know if you've got something working!

Answer (score -2):

This seems to be a good one: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/ftpclientclass.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't answer the question.  It's an FTP client that runs on Windows.

Answer (score -2):

These guys are known for making the premier network libraries: http://www.nsoftware.com/ipworks